Overheating truck
2012 Dodge ram 1500 5.7 hemi changed upper radiator hose clutch fan thermostat radiator cap there are no leaks from the radiator or the water pump no noise coming from the water pump but the truck still overheats

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What exactly is your question?
